# removing an image after x amount of clicks in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I just need to know how to tell a  PHP page via MYSQL database to remove an image after certain amount of clicks?

for example i upload an image via php/mysql (this bit works by the way) and then I need to tell the php to remove that image once there has been 20 or 30 etc etc clicks on it.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how do you determine that an image has already 20 or 30 clicks?

Comment: maybe saving the clicks in the mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to record each click on your database:

```
imageId | image | clicks
1       | ...   | 5
2       | ...   | 10
```

then you can add a `WHERE` condition to your `SELECT` query:

```
$clicksMax = 20;
$query = 
"SELECT `image`, `imageId`
FROM `image`
WHERE `clicks` < $clicksMax";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. any chance you could explain it a bit further as I am bit lost. i'll muddle through!

Comment: well, I assume the first part of your answer is related to the mysql database. So, I have a table called "products" and a cloumn called "click". the first question is that How do I use your second code to add the clicks to the mysql database when they reached 20 clicks according to your second code?

Comment: You just need to increase the clicks column on each click - you can do it with jQuery -> Ajax -> PHP -> SQL. Research this a bit, I'm sure you'll manage!

Answer (score 0):

Better solution to capture the clicks via `ajax` request on each click update the coloumn of clicks for the image by adding 1 and when you going to add 1 there you can check the value if it is greater than your desired clicks you will remove that image from `html` + `database` also.